# Select and Update are returning/updating different number of records with same join

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, join, sql-update

Pardon my long question but I am more looking for troubleshooting advice. Both `A.DR_CR` and `B.DR_CR` has `distinct` values `'D'` or `'C'` I wanted to audit the number of records in table A where the value will be changed (D to C or vice versa) hence I wrote the following select before update statement. The join keys `ID` and `SRC_TRAN_ID` are NOT unique in both tables.

The select statement shows the count of credit updated to debit `(CR_TO_DB)` is 588017
and `DB_TO_CR` is 924119

But when I run the update with the same join condition, I see that number of credits updated to debit are 3257 LESS than the above select result for `CR_TO_DB` and similarly, `DB_TO_CR` count is 3257 more than 924119.

I am unable to troubleshoot why the update does NOT update the number of records returned by the select with same join condition. Please help.

```
SELECT 
(CASE WHEN A.DR_CR != B.DR_CR AND A.DR_CR = 'C' AND B.DR_CR='D' THEN 1 END) CR_TO_DB
,(CASE WHEN A.DR_CR != B.DR_CR AND A.DR_CR = 'D' AND B.DR_CR='C' THEN 1 END) DB_TO_CR
INTO MTL_REPORT
FROM #STAGING_TRANSACTIONS A
JOIN #CLEAN_MTL_UPDATE B
ON A.SRC_TRANID = B.SRC_TRANID
AND A.ID = B.ID


UPDATE A
        SET
        A.DR_CR = B.DR_CR
        FROM #STAGING_TRANSACTIONS A
        JOIN #CLEAN_MTL_UPDATE B
        ON A.SRC_TRANID = B.SRC_TRANID
        AND A.ID = B.ID
```

Comment: The pair SRC_TRANID and ID exists multiple times in one or both of your temp tables.  The update will filter down to unique keys and only report the actual number of records that were updated while the select will report potentially duplicate records from A's perspective.  Try this query for both of your temp tables.  If either comes back with records, you have duplicate results. SELECT ID, SRC_TRANID, COUNT(*) FROM #STAGING_TRANSACTIONS GROUP BY ID, SRC_TRANID HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;

Answer (score 0):

I'll explain it in simpler terms with smaller data sets. Given these two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE TableA (Col1 INT, Col2 INT, Col3 VARCHAR(10))
CREATE TABLE TableB (Col1 INT, Col2 INT, Col3 VARCHAR(10))

INSERT INTO TableA (Col1, Col2, Col3) VALUES (1, 1, 'a')
INSERT INTO TableA (Col1, Col2, Col3) VALUES (1, 1, 'b')
INSERT INTO TableA (Col1, Col2, Col3) VALUES (1, 2, 'c')

INSERT INTO TableB (Col1, Col2, Col3) VALUES (1, 1, 'd')
INSERT INTO TableB (Col1, Col2, Col3) VALUES (1, 1, 'e')
INSERT INTO TableB (Col1, Col2, Col3) VALUES (1, 2, 'f')
```

This query will give you 5 rows because `Col1=1, Col2=1` exists twice on both tables.

```
SELECT *
FROM TableA
JOIN TableB ON TableA.Col1 = TableB.Col1 AND TableA.Col2 = TableB.Col2
```

You get pairs of Col3 like this:

```
a, d
b, d
a, e
b, e
c, f
```

An UPDATE statement using the same join essentially filters out the unique records and only reports on them. After all, you want to know how many records were affected.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation. So if I remove the duplicate rows from both tables, will my update count and audit count match?

Comment: I would imagine so. But does it matter to you?

Comment: It does matter to me as I want to check not only the update count but also the count where value was changed (from D to C or vice versa)